# Orbeon Form Builder customisation

Tags: customization, orbeon

I want to build an application using the Orbeon platform services.

Is it possible to change the look and feel of Orbeon form builder? i.e. 
change the logo, the color, localize the system messages etc... so it can be embedded in a custom app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely:

- [Custom CSS stylesheets](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/styling/css.html) will enable you to do most of the changes you have in mind.
- You can [set a property to change the logo](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#default-logo) showing out-of-the-box in Form Builder and Form Runner.
- Should you need to localize Form Builder or Form Runner themselves to add a new language or complete the resources for a partially [supported language](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/feature/localization.html), see [Localizing Orbeon Forms](https://doc.orbeon.com/contributors/localizing-orbeon-forms.html).